# Using xmlstarlet to pattern match element tags

Tags: xml, dynamic, tags, element, xmlstarlet

I am trying to determine how to use `xmlstarlet` to get the `xml` tag and values when the tag elements aren't constant.

for example,

**Input file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"?>
<ST>
  <Data3020>
    <value>110</value>
    <detailType>N/A</detailType>
  </Data3020>
  <Data3030>
    <value>10</value>
    <detailType>N/A</detailType>
  </Data3030>
  <Data3040>
    <value>70</value>
    <detailType>N/A</detailType>
  </Data3040>
  <Data3080>
    <value>770</value>
    <detailType>N/A</detailType>
  </Data3080>
  <Data3090>
    <value>44</value>
    <detailType>N/A</detailType>
  </Data3090>
</ST>
```

**Expected Output**:

```
BoxName|value|detailType|
Data3020|100|N/A|
Data3030|10|N/A|
Data3030|70|N/A|
Data3040|770|N/A|
Data3050|44|N/A|
```

I tried the following to get the tag name and the values separately but I can't figure out how to combine them

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "/ST/*" -v "name()" -nl test.xml
```

```
Data3020
Data3030
Data3040
Data3080
Data3090
```

```
xmlstarlet sel --template --value-of "//ST" test.xml


110
N/A


10
N/A


70
N/A


770
N/A


44
N/A
```

Comment: From where comes column 2 with 110, 10, 70, 770, 44?

Comment: `xmlstarlet sel --template --value-of "//ST" file` gives `0` integer for each rows

Comment: /ST/*/concat(local-name(.)," | ", value, " | ", detailType)

Comment: Hi @GillesQuénot, I have modified my post to fix it. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel):

```
xidel --xquery '
    for $n in /ST/*
        let $name := $n/name()
        let $val  := $n/value
        let $type := $n/detailType
    return concat($name, "|", $val, "|", $type, "|")
' file
```

Or re-using the XPath @Yitzhak Khabinsky given in comments:

```
xidel -e '/ST/*/concat(name(),"|", value, "|", detailType)' file
```

or with `saxon-lint` (my own project):

```
saxon-lint --xpath '/ST/*/concat(name(),"|", value, "|", detailType)' file
```

Or with [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) via the comment of @Cyrus:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '/ST/*' \
    -v "concat(name(),'|',value,'|',detailType,'|')" \
    -n file
```

```
Data3020|110|N/A|
Data3030|10|N/A|
Data3040|70|N/A|
Data3080|770|N/A|
Data3090|44|N/A|
```

Comment: Thanks! any chance this can be achieved using xmlstarlet? I don't have xidel on my dev and prod environment hosts.

Comment: Check edited post with `xmlstarlet` solution as well